# Error installing node.js on docker-compose build

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, sap-commerce-cloud

I am running hybris in a docker environment. However, I need node.js to build the frontend. When I run docker-compose build the following error occurs.

There is an error installing node.js to generate the image.

I tried to get into the container and install node.js through the terminal. Unsuccessfully.

```
FROM miltex/jdk:1.8

RUN yum makecache fast && yum -y update && yum clean all

RUN curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && yum -y install nodejs
...
...

Error Log:

Step 3/21 : RUN curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && yum -y install nodejs
 ---> Running in 31a353bc3566
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: mirror.ufam.edu.br
 * extras: mirror.ufam.edu.br
 * updates: mirror.ufam.edu.br
No package nodejs available.
Error: Nothing to do
ERROR: Service 'hybris' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && yum -y install nodejs' returned a non-zero code: 1

C:\developer\docker\hybrisDevs>
```

Comment: Try to remove silent to see is there any warning or message which can give you some clue to trace the error

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem and failed. Ran the `yum` and `curl` commands within a `miltex/jdk:1.8` container, got `Package 2:nodejs-8.16.2-1nodesource.x86_64 already installed and latest version` as the output. Ran `node -v` and got `v8.16.2`.

Can you post the entire Dockerfile, maybe some other command is messing this up?

Comment: I solved the problem.